# Using results of Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

Suppose I have function f:

```
f[x_, y_] := 50000 + x 30000 + y 35000;
```

Now I want to find the x and y when f[]<=200000.
I use Reduce:

```
Reduce[f[x, y] <= 200000 && 1 <= x <= 8 && 1 <= y <= 8 , {x,y}, Integers]
```

The result is:

```
(x == 1 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && y == 2) || (x == 1 && y == 3) || 
(x == 2 && y == 1) || (x == 2 && y == 2) || (x == 3 && y == 1)
```

Now I would like to use these results back into f[] but it requires formatting.
I use:

```
results = Reduce[f[x, y] <= 200000 && 1 <= x <= 8 && 1 <= y <= 8, 
           {x, y},Integers] /. 
             Or[a__, b__] -> {a, b} /. 
              And[a_ == c_, b_ == d_] -> {c, d}
```

And I use:

```
f[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ results
```

to get:

```
{115000, 150000, 185000, 145000, 180000, 175000}
```

I wonder if this is the right way to do this or if it can be done easier. It seems reduce can generate different (depending on the equations of course) formats of the results and this would mean that for every type  of result new rules will be needed. Is this a fact of life?

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for editing. Still kind of struggling to get it nice..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You may want to look at the documentation for [`ToRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToRules.html).  When applied to the output of `Reduce` you provided, the result is

```
Sequence[{x -> 1, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, y -> 2}, {x -> 1, y -> 3}, 
         {x -> 2, y -> 1}, {x -> 2, y -> 2}, {x -> 3, y -> 1}]
```

If you want to substitute this back to `f[x,y]`, put curly braces to turn the sequence into a list and use [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
f[x,y] /. {%}
```

This will give the desired output `{115000, 150000, 185000, 145000, 180000, 175000}`.

Comment: +1, I was looking for `ToRules` and couldn't remember it.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for editing my answer.  I was so excited that I could finally contribute something that it did not occur to me to provide links or use the code block.

Comment: Not a problem. It was a nice answer.

Comment: `ToRules` is great. I didn't know that!

Answer (score 4):

I'd do the following:

```
res = Reduce[f[x, y] <= 200000 && 1 <= x <= 8 && 1 <= y <= 8, {x, y}, Integers];
vals = Apply[List, res[[All, All, 2]], {0, 1}]
(*
==> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}}
*)
```

which uses `Part` in the form `res[[All,All,2]]` to get only the numerical values, and then [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) to replace the `Or` and `And` in the logical construct with `List`. For the second part, I'd again use `Apply` in its second short form:

```
f @@@ vals
```

Answer (score 1):

```
50000 + x*30000 + y*35000 /. FindInstance[50000 + x*30000 + y*35000 < 200000 && 
    ((x == 1 && y == 1) || (x == 1 && y == 2) || (x == 1 && y == 3) || 
     (x == 2 && y == 1) || (x == 2 && y == 2) || (x == 3 && y == 1)), {x, y}, 
   Integers, 6]
```

(*
==>

{115000, 150000, 185000, 145000, 180000, 175000}

*)

Comment: What about when there are more results? It seems that I first need to know how many results there are. I mean the number 6 at the end. Is it better to use FindInstance for these type of equations?

Comment: You can put 137 or whatever instead of 6. The documentation says:     FindInstance[expr,vars,dom,n] will return a shorter list if the total number of instances is less than n.       Whether FindInstance is better: I do not know.