# Splitting Logical Expression in list of expressions

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation, logic

I have long results of a `Reduce` statement in the form of `{(expr1) || (expr2) || (expr3) || ...}`

I am looking for a way to split them into a list `{expr1, expr2, expr3, ...}`

Even better, I would be happy to split the internal expressions to lists at the '&&` operators as well.

Comment: So how do you want a mixture of `And`s and `Or`s to be treated?

Comment: Luckily the || are outside the expressions, and internally the expressions only have &&.

I would probably prefer to have it converted into some canonical form first.

Comment: Now that you bring it up: look at `BooleanConvert[]`.

Comment: In certain cases results of `Reduce` can be transformed into rules by using `ToRules`, then  this post might  be helpful [Assign the results from a Solve to variable(s)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables). Nevertheless you should remember that `Reduce` and `Solve` are not  equivalent in general  [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129).

Comment: That was helpful - thanks! (though ToRules didn't apply in this case).

Comment: Related: [(1809)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1809/121), [(10833)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10833/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the expression is inside a `List` use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) at level 1

```
list1 = {(expr1) || (expr2) || (expr3)};

List @@@ list1

(*  {{expr1, expr2, expr3}}  *)

list2 = {(expr1) && (expr2) && (expr3)};

List @@@ list2

(*  {{expr1, expr2, expr3}}  *)
```

If there is no external `List` then just use `Apply`

```
list3 = (expr1) || (expr2) || (expr3);

List @@ list3

(*  {expr1, expr2, expr3}  *)

list4 = (expr1) && (expr2) && (expr3);

List @@ list4

(*  {expr1, expr2, expr3}  *)
```

Comment: I found out Level does the same thing. Converting to normal form using BooleanConvert prior to applying it helped. Many thanks!